# App UIImagePickerController crashes in orientation app iphone ios 6

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

The orientation of my app is portrait for all view, other then MPMoviePlayerViewController ,It is in landscape.

Now when i am trying to open camera using UIImagePickerController, my app crashes,

I read some where to subclass the UIImage picker controller, i did this,

```
        - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
           {
             return YES;
            }  

         - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
         {
             return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
         }

         - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
         {
             return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
         }
```

my crash resolved, but my picker is reversed,
Please help me out .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

```
return YES;
```

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```

}